# BroadcastReceiver from MainActivity does not receive extra

Tags: java, android

Consider this scenario, there's three classes involved: this is an alarm app, you want to show a button when the alarm service is on and hide it when the alarm is off. I want to BroadcastReceiver in MainActivity receive an extra from the other two classes to determine whether should the button should be showed or hidden.

This is my BroadcastReceiver in MainActivity, buttonVisibility should be receiving extras.

```java
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                buttonVisibility = getIntent().getStringExtra("visibility");

                switch (buttonVisibility) {
                    case "visible":
                        showButtonMatikanAlarm();
                        break;
                    case "gone":
                        hideButtonMatikanAlarm();
                        break;
                    default:
                        //do nothing
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
};
```

On the `onCreate` method I already register the broadcastReceiver:

```java
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("anim button"));
```

This is the snippet of code that send a broadcast to show button, for context this is in a receiver class and inside an `onRecieve` method:

```java
Intent intentShowButtonMatikan = new Intent("anim button");
intentShowButtonMatikan.putExtra("visibility", "visible");
context.sendBroadcast(intentShowButtonMatikan);
```

Code that send a broadcast to hide button, for context this resides in a method inside a dialog class. When a button of a dialog clicked, it should send extra:

```java
Intent intentHideButtonMatikan = new Intent("anim button");
intentHideButtonMatikan.putExtra("visibility", "gone");
getContext().sendBroadcast(intentHideButtonMatikan);
```

When the code runs, BroadcastReciever is called but never get the extra and `buttonVisibility` returns null. What's wrong?

Any help will be appreciated. I'm a starter at Android, sorry if it turns out a noob question.

Comment: Use this `intent.getStringExtra("visibility");` instead of `getIntent().getStringExtra("visibility");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your method *onReceive(Context context, **Intent intent**)* is your passed intent that you should extract data from,

so maybe instead of calling **getIntent()** directly extract data from intent like this :

```
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
   buttonVisibility = intent.getStringExtra("visibility"); }
```

because by calling **getIntent()** your are getting the Intent that started the activity and not the receiver.

**but the correct way to send a broad cast is this way** :

- In your manifest register the receiver :

  ```
  <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver" android:enabled="true">
   <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="broad.cast.action.visibility" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```
- Or directly if it's a child of your Activity :

  ```
  registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("broad.cast.action.visibility"));
  ```
- Initialize your Intent :

  ```
  Intent yourIntent = new Intent("broad.cast.action.visibility");
  yourIntent.putExtra("visibility", "visible");
  sendBroadcast(yourIntent);
  ```
- get data :

  ```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals("broad.cast.action.visibility")){
       buttonVisibility = intent.getStringExtra("visibility");

          switch (buttonVisibility) {
              case "visible":
                  showButtonMatikanAlarm();
                  break;
              case "gone":
                  hideButtonMatikanAlarm();
                  break;
              default:
                  //do nothing
                  break;
          }
   }
  }
  ```

> **Note**, view visibility is an int, so instead of passing visibility as  a string you can pass it directly as an int.

```
intentShowButtonMatikan.putExtra("visibility", View.VISIBLE); //Or View.GONE;
```

and inside your broadcast, you don't need to check the string, you can directly set the visibility using :

```
visibilty = intent.getIntExtra("visibility", View.GONE /* <-- Default value*/);
view.setVisibility(visibilty);
```